# Efficient way to find if an IP is in a list of subnets that are stored in DynamoDB

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, subnet

I'm trying to create an API that I can send an IP address to and the response will contain the subnet that the IP belongs to (if it belongs to any in the table).
I have a list of subnets all stored in a table in DynamoDB like such:

```
subnet
45.221.27.0/24
102.215.216.0/23
192.168.0.0/16
etc...
```

I can't seem to figure out how I could efficiently query the table to determine which subnet an IP belongs to. I am using a Lambda to make the request so I am trying to avoid reading all the subnets in because that will use a lot of memory. I'm also trying to avoid scanning the table rather than querying because that can become too expensive.

I've been thinking about different ways of storing the subnets in the table such that it becomes possible to get more granular with queries but I also feel like I'm overcomplicating something that shouldn't be so complex.

Comment: If any of these CIDRs are for VPC then they're going to be identical or overlapping, presumably.

Answer (score 2):

How funny, I'm actually writing a blog on this. I'll add the link once it's published. There's a lot of interesting scaling topics related to this problem for how to load and query with max efficiency. Here's the simplest approach:

Use a singular Partition Key value (that is, the same for all items). Use the range start IP address as the Sort Key. But make it the 32-bit numeric value of the IP address not the string value, because we need to sort by it and sorting by the string value is problematic. (All IP addresses are really just 32-bit numbers underneath.) The other attributes will be the metadata you want to retrieve.

The lookup then is to issue a `Query` where the PK is the singular value and the SK is <= the lookup IP address (in numeric form).

The one caveat is you need to make sure that any gaps in the IP address range data set need to be filled during the load with marker items saying "gap here", otherwise a lookup that hits the gap will return the range ahead of the gap.

Comment: You are an absolute legend! That works really well! Thank you for your help!

Comment: In case anyone else is interested in the blog, I'm gonna go out and limb and guess this is it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-1-scaling-dynamodb-how-partitions-hot-keys-and-split-for-heat-impact-performance/ - super interesting read, thanks!